# How to keep the drop down list selection after web page refresh using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I am writing and application using AngularJs, HTML and PHP. In the application I have a dropdown list, which when an option is selected a table is populated with related data drawn from a database. I can add to or delete info from the table. That works perfectly. However, the challenge I have is that each time the table is edited, the web page refreshes/route is reloaded and the drop down list returns to its default value. The effect of this is the user having to manually reselect the dropdown list value to carryout each operation on the table. 
How can I alter the code to keep/persist the last selected option value and have the said dropdown list option selected when the webpage/route reloads?

I have seen many help responses to setting initial default value for dropdown lists. However that is not what I am trying to achieve. I am trying  to set the post reload value or value after the webpage reloads.

Below is a part of what I have tried. I am at my whits end trying to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Problem Solved 
HTML before changes

```html
<select id="b_year" ng-options="b.year for b in budgets track by b.year" ng-model="b.selectedBudget" ng-change="getBudgetItems(b.selectedBudget.year)" required><option value="">-- Choose budget year --</option></select>
```

HTML with solution changes

```html
<select id="b_year" ng-options="b.year for b in budgets" ng-model="b.selectedBudget" ng-init="b.selectedBudget" ng-selected="getBudgetItems(b.selectedBudget.year)" required><option value="">-- Choose budget year --</option></select>
```

Controller snippet before changes

```js
$scope.reloadRoute();
$scope.items.push({'line_item': li.line_item, 'weight': li.weight, 'allocated': li.allocated});

localStorage['b_year'] = year; //Store the selected year in local storage for later use
budget_size = server.getBudgetSize(); 

for(var i = 0; i < budget_size; i++){
  if($scope.budgets[i].year === localStorage['b_year']){ 
    $scope.b.selectedBudget[i] = localStorage['b_year'];
  }else{
  
  }
}
```

Controller with solution changes

```js
app.controller(.... {
    ....
 (function(){
    $http.get( //Get info on budgets
        "http://localhost/TrGway/getbudgetinfo.php"
    )  
    .success(function(data){
       $scope.budgets = data.budgets;                
        for(var i = 0; i < data.budgets.length; i++){
            if($scope.budgets[i].year === selectedYear){ 

               $scope.b = {};

               $scope.b.selectedBudget = $scope.budgets[i];
            }      
        }                          
      
    })
    .error(function(data){
       $scope.message = "Error!! Getting Budget Info Failed: " + data;
    });
})(); 
    ....
$scope.$watch("b.selectedBudget.year", function(item) {
       localStorage.setItem("selectedYear", item);
});

});
```

```js
App.controller('budgetCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$route', 'BudgetService', function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $route, BudgetService){
    
    (function(){ 
        $http.get( //Get info on budgets
            "http://localhost/TrGway/getbudgetinfo.php"
        )  
        .success(function(data){ 
           server.setBudgets(data.budgets);//Set the budget info in the BudgetService for 
             //later usage anywhere in the program;    
           $scope.budgets = data.budgets; 
           budget_size = server.getBudgetSize();
            
           server.getBudgetInfo();
        })
        .error(function(data){
            $scope.message = "Error!! Getting Budget Info Failed: " + data;
        });
    })(); 
    
    (function(){ //Get Line Items Info to populate the table
        $http.get(
            "http://localhost/TrGway/lineItemInfo.php"
        )  
        .success(function(data){
           server.setLineItems(data.items);
           $scope.items = data.items;            
           server.getLineItemsInfo();            
        })
        .error(function(data){
            $scope.message = "Error!! Getting Line Items Info Failed: "+data;
        });
    })();
        
    $scope.addBudget = function(budget){        
       if( budget.year < new Date().getFullYear() ){ 
          alert("Budgets cannot be created retroactively.\n\
                 \nPlease enter a budget year greater than "+ new Date().getFullYear() );
          $scope.budget.year = "";
       }else{ 
         server.addBudget(budget); 
         server.getBudgetInfo();
         $scope.budgets = server.getBudgets();
         $scope.budget = {};//Clear the add budget form
      }
    };
    
    $scope.getBudgetItems = function(year){ 
 /*This is where info on the budget for the selected year is retrieved and passed to the table
   This works great every time*/
       if( year === undefined ){ //If no year is selected do nothing
         $scope.budget_amount = 0; 
         $scope.budget_amount_used = 0;
         $scope.budget_amount_remaining = 0;
       }else{ 
         Budgets = server.getBudgets(); 
         budget_size = server.getBudgetSize(); 
         for(var i = 0; i < budget_size; i++){
             if(Budgets[i].year === year){ 
                $scope.budget_amount = Budgets[i].starting_amount; 
                $scope.budget_amount_used = Budgets[i].amount_used;
                $scope.budget_amount_remaining = Budgets[i].running_balance;
                amount_remaining = Budgets[i].starting_amount - Budgets[i].amount_used;
                percent_used += (Budgets[i].amount_used / Budgets[i].starting_amount * 100);
                server.setSelectedBudget(Budgets[i]);
             }else{
                //$scope.budget_amount = 0; 
             }           
         }
         server.setPercentUsed(percent_used);
         server.setPercentRemaining( 100 - percent_used);
         server.setAmountRemaining(amount_remaining);
       }      
    };
    /*======================= THIS IS WHERE THE CHALLENGE IS ====================*/
    $scope.addLineItem = function(li, b){ 
 /*This is where the List items are added to the table before page reload*/
        if(($scope.budget_amount_used-0 + li.allocated-0) > $scope.budget_amount){
            alert("Budgeted amount exceeded!!!\nPlease consider revising");
            $location.path('editbudget');
            $scope.li.weight = 0;
            $scope.li.allocation = 0;
        }else{          
   server.setSelectedBudgetYear(b.selectedBudget.year); //Save selected year to a variable
   server.addLineItem(li, b); //Add the new Line items row to database

   $scope.reloadRoute();
   $scope.items.push({'line_item': li.line_item, 'weight': li.weight, 'allocated': li.allocated});

   $scope.b = {};
   //$scope.b.selectedBudget = localStorage.getItem("selected");
   $scope.$watch("b.selectedBudget.year", function(item) {
    localStorage.setItem("selected", item);
   });         
        
          //$scope.b.selectedBudget.year = server.getSelectedBudgetYear();   //I tried this also           
        } 
        $scope.li.line_item = "";
        $scope.li.weight = 0;
        $scope.li.allocation = 0; 
        
  $scope.b.selectedBudget = localStorage.getItem("selected");
  
        /* LEAVING THIS SO YOU CAN SEE WHAT ELSE I HAVE TRIED
    $scope.b = {};
          $scope.b.selectedBudget = localStorage.getItem("selectedBudget");
          $scope.watch("b.selected", function(item) {
             localStorage.setItem("selected", item);
          });
    $scope.b.selectedBudget = localStorage['b_year'];
        */
        
       /* LEAVING THIS SO YOU CAN SEE WHAT ELSE I HAVE TRIED
  budget_size = server.getBudgetSize(); 
         for(var i = 0; i < budget_size; i++){
    if($scope.budgets[i].year === server.getSelectedBudgetYear()){ 
    $scope.b.selectedBudget.year = server.getSelectedBudgetYear();
    }else{
     
    }           
        }*/
       
    };
 
 $scope.deleteLineItem = function(row, b){        
        $http({
           method: "post",
           url: "http://localhost/TrGway/deleteLineItem.php",
           crossDomain: true,
           data:{
               'seq': row.seq,
               'year': row.year,
               'allocated':row.allocated,
               'starting_amount': b.selectedBudget.starting_amount,
               'amount_used': b.selectedBudget.amount_used,
               'running_balance': b.selectedBudget.running_balance
           },
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
           }
        })  
        .success(function(response){                                
            if(response.toString() === "success"){             
              var index = -1;  
              var itemsArr = eval( $scope.items );
              for( var i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; i++ ) {
                if( itemsArr[i].seq === row.seq ) {
                  index = i;
                  break;
                }
              }
              if( index === -1 ) {
                alert( "Something has gone wrong!!\nLine item was not deleted.\nPlease try again" );
              } 
                server.reset();
                server.reload();
                $scope.budget_percent_used = server.getPercentUsed()-0;
                $scope.budget_percent_remaining = server.getPercentRemaining()-0;
                $scope.budget_amount_used = server.getAmountUsed()-0; 
                $scope.budget_amount_remaining = server.getAmountRemaining()-0;
               
                server.setTotalWeighting($scope.totalweighting + row.weight)-0;
                server.setPercentUsed(server.getTotalWeighting())-0;
                server.setPercentRemaining(100 - server.getPercentUsed())-0;
                $scope.items.splice( index, 1 ); //Remove the row with matching index/seq value
                $scope.totalweighting = server.getTotalWeighting(); 
                $scope.budget_percent_used = server.getPercentUsed()-0;
                $scope.budget_percent_remaining = server.getPercentRemaining()-0;*/
                $scope.reloadRoute();                 
            }else{ //If deleting the line item failed
                $location.path('editbudget');
                $scope.budgetmessage = "Line Item Update Failed: "+response;
            }
        })
        .error(function(response){ //If there was an error connecting to the server
            $scope.budgetmessage = "Error!! Updating Line Item Failed: "+response;
        });        
       row.isEditing = false;
    };
        
    $scope.updateLineItem = function(row){
        $http({
           method: "post",
           url: "http://localhost/TrGway/updateLineItem.php",
           crossDomain: true,
           data:{
               'seq': row.seq,
               'line_item': row.line_item,
               'weight': row.weight,
               'allocated': row.allocated
           },
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
           }
        })  
        .success(function(response){                                          
            if(response.toString() === "success"){ 
                $location.path('editbudget');
            }else{
                $location.path('editbudget');
                $scope.budgetmessage = "Line Item Update Failed: "+response;
            }
        })
        .error(function(response){
            $scope.budgetmessage = "Error!! Updating Line Item Failed: "+response;
        });        
       row.isEditing = false;
    };
            
    $scope.cancelLineItemEditing = function(row){
        row.isEditing = false;
    };
    
    $scope.updateBudget = function(b){
        $http({
           method: "post",
           url: "http://localhost/TrGway/updatebudget.php",
           crossDomain: true,
           data:{
               'year': b.selectedBudget.year,                   
               'starting_amount': b.edit_starting_amount
           },
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
           }
        })  
        .success(function(response){                                   
            if(response.toString() === "success"){ 
                server.setStartingAmount(b.edit_starting_amount);
                var line_items = server.getLineItems();
                var start_amount = server.getStartingAmount(); 
                var total_weight = 0;
                var amount_used = 0;
                var amount_remaining = 0;
                var percent_used = 0;
                var percent_remaining = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i < line_items.length; i++){
                    //Update the line items on the page immediately
                    line_items[i].weight = ( line_items[i].allocated / start_amount) * 100;
                    total_weight += line_items[i].weight;
                    amount_used += line_items[i].allocated-0;
                    //Update the line items in the database immediately
                    $scope.updateLineItem(line_items[i]);
                }
                                
                server.load();
                
                percent_used = ( amount_used / start_amount) * 100; 
                amount_remaining = start_amount - amount_used;
                percent_remaining = 100 - percent_used;
                
                server.setLineItems(line_items);                
                server.setTotalWeighting(total_weight);
                server.setAmountUsed(amount_used);
                server.setPercentUsed(percent_used);
                server.setAmountRemaining(amount_remaining);
                server.setPercentRemaining(percent_remaining);
                
                $scope.items = server.getLineItems();
                $scope.total = 0;
                $scope.total = server.getStartingAmount();
                $scope.totalweighting = server.getTotalWeighting()-0; 
                $scope.budget_amount_used = server.getAmountUsed()-0;        
                $scope.budget_percent_used = server.getPercentUsed()-0;
                $scope.budget_percent_remaining = server.getPercentRemaining()-0; 
                $scope.budget_amount_remaining = server.getAmountRemaining()-0;
               
                $location.path('editbudget');
            }else{
                $location.path('editbudget');
                $scope.budgetmessage = "Budget Update Failed: "+response;
            }
        })
        .error(function(response){
            $scope.budgetmessage = "Error!! Updating Budget Failed: "+response;
        });        
       
        $scope.b = {};
    };
        
    $scope.reloadRoute = function(){ 
       $route.reload();
       server.reload();
    //alert('Loaded!!');
    };
}]);
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs" id="breadcrumbs">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Add/Edit line Items</a></li>        
    <li style="float: right" ng-controller="authCtrl"><a ng-click="logout();">Logout</a></li>
    <li style="float: right"><a href="#/dashboard">Back</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="row" ng-cloak="" ng-controller="budgetCtrl">   
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <section>
        <form name="LineItemForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <fieldset>            
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width: 150px" colspan="1">Select Budget Year To Edit Line Items</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="1">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                      <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE YEAR IS SELECTED -->
                      <select id="b_year" ng-options="b.year for b in budgets track by b.year" ng-model="b.selectedBudget" ng-change="getBudgetItems(b.selectedBudget.year);" ng-selected="" required>
                        <option value="">-- Choose budget year --</option> 
                      </select>                    
                    </div>
                  </td>                  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width: 150px" colspan="1">{{b.budgetmessage}}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>                        
                        <h3>Add Line Item Here</h3>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="line_item">Line Item</label>
                          <div class="col-md-7">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="line_item" id="line_item" ng-model="li.line_item" ng-disabled="!b.selectedBudget" required/>
                          </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="weight">weighting %</label>
                          <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="number:2" class="form-control" name="weight" id="weight" ng-init="li.weight = 0" ng-model="li.weight" ng-disabled="!b.selectedBudget || !li.line_item || li.line_item.length<5" required/>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="allocated">Allocated $</label>
                          <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="number:2" class="form-control" name="allocated" id="allocated" placeholder="{{li.allocated = (budget_amount * li.weight) / 100 | currency}}" ng-init="li.allocated=0"  ng-model="li.allocated" ng-disabled="!b.selectedBudget || !li.weight" required />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="padding-right: 100px;"> 
                          <span class="lbl col-sm-5"> </span>               
                          <div class="col-md-7 message" >
                            <span id="message" class="block input-icon input-icon-right">{{message}}</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>   
                        <div class="form-group">        
                          <div style="padding-right:100px">
                            <button type="submit" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="addLineItem(li, b)" data-ng-disabled="LineItemForm.$invalid || li.weight===0 || li.line_item.length < 5">
                                Add Line Item
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div>
      <section>
        <div class="col-lg-14"  style="float: right">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                  <table class="table table-striped" >
                      <thead>
                        <tr>                   
                           <!--<th>Index</th>-->
                           <th>Line Items</th><th  style="width: 150px">% Weighting</th><th style="width: 150px">Allocation $</th><th style="width: 120px">Tasks</th><!---->
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in items" ng-model="items" ng-if="row.year === b.selectedBudget.year"><!--<td>{{$index+1}}</td>-->
                         <td title="'Line Item'" ng-switch="row.isEditing" ng-class="line_item.$dirty ? 'bg-warning' : ''" ng-form="name" demo-tracked-table-cell>
                          <span ng-switch-default class="editable-text">{{row.line_item}}</span>
                          <div class="controls" ng-class="line_item.$invalid && line_item.$dirty ? 'has-error' : ''" ng-switch-when="true">
                            <input type="text" name="line_item" ng-model="row.line_item" class="editable-input form-control input-sm" required />
                          </div>
                         </td>
                         <td>{{ row.weight = row.allocated / budget_amount * 100 | number: 2 }}</td>                        
                         <td title="'Allocation'" ng-switch="row.isEditing" ng-class="allocated.$dirty ? 'bg-warning' : ''" ng-form="allocated" demo-tracked-table-cell>
                          <span ng-switch-default class="editable-text">{{ row.allocated | currency }}</span>
                          <div class="controls" ng-class="allocated.$invalid && allocated.$dirty ? 'has-error' : ''" ng-switch-when="true">
                            <input type="text" name="allocated" ng-model="row.allocated" class="editable-input form-control input-sm" required/>
                          </div>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                           <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="updateLineItem(row)" ng-if="row.isEditing" ng-disabled="rowForm.$pristine || rowForm.$invalid"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
                           <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="cancelLineItemEditing(row)" ng-if="row.isEditing"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                           <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="row.isEditing = true" ng-if="!row.isEditing"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                           <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="deleteLineItem(row, b)" ng-if="!row.isEditing"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <h5>
                            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                               <b>TOTAL (Budget Estimate)</b>     
                            </span> 
                          </h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <h5>
                            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                               <b>{{ totalweighting =  budget_amount > 0 ? 100 : 0 | number:2 }}%</b><!---->
                            </span> 
                          </h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <h5>
                            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                               <b>{{ budget_amount | currency }}</b> 
                            </span> 
                          </h5>
                        </td><td></td>                
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <h5>
                            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                               <b>BUDGET AMOUNT USED</b>    
                            </span> 
                          </h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <h5>
                            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                               <b>{{ budget_percent_used = budget_amount_used > 0 ? budget_amount_used * 100/budget_amount : 0 | number:2 }}%</b>
                              <!--Adding the -0 forces the compiler to treat the value as a number-->
                            </span> 
                          </h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <h5>
                            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                <!--{{ budget_amount_used + li.allocated | currency }}--> 
                                <b>{{ budget_amount_used | currency }}</b> 
                            </span> 
                          </h5>
                        </td><td></td>                
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <h5>
                            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                               <b>BUDGETED AMOUNT REMAINING</b>    
                            </span> 
                          </h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <h5>
                            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                               <b>{{ budget_percent_remaining = 100 - budget_percent_used | number:2 }}%</b>
                              <!--Adding the -0 forces the compiler to treat the value as a number-->
                            </span> 
                          </h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <h5>
                            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                <!--{{ budget_amount_remaining - li.allocated | currency }}-->
                                <b>{{ budget_amount_remaining | currency }}</b>
                            </span> 
                          </h5>
                        </td><td></td>                
                      </tr>
                </tbody>
                  </table>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
          </div>
      </section>      
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: In which function is the second snippet located?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$scope.b.selectedBudget = localStorage['b_year'];` without a loop and a condition?

Comment: Tamas Hegedus, Thanks for your quick reply.. The second snippet is located in a controller within a javascript file.

Comment: You did not set `$scope.b = {};` before `$scope.b.selectedBudget = localStorage.getItem("selected");`. That means it threw an error, and the rest of the controller didnt even run. If you open the developer console you can see the error there.

Comment: @Tamas Hegedus, Thanks for your response and I apologize for taking so long to reply. I have tried setting the $scope.b = {}; before $scope.b.selectedBudget = localStorage.getItem("selected"); but that has not worked either. I believe the selected value is being overwritten, but I haven't figured out where. I am going to look through the code again and report my findings. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: @Tamas Hegedus, Thanks for your help. I will implement your suggestion in the controller and give you feedback.

Comment: @Tamas Hegedus, THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!. Problem solved. I had to make a few changes in my code and I got it to work. Thanks to you pointing me in the right direction. I am going to add the answer below so you can see what was done and also that anyone else with a similar issue may be helped also.

Comment: Instead of posting the solution you used in the question body, it is much better to create a self answer.  These type of answers are encouraged, and not only help keep clear the separation between question and solution, but also make it much easier for others having the same kind of trouble to find the solution.

Comment: I dont think the ng-init part does anything at all. Anyway, if you have a nice angular example with asynchronous initialization of controls, then I advise you to make a blog post somewhere. StackOverflow focuses on specific problems.

Comment: @Clales, Thanks for the suggestion, I will do so.

Comment: can you answer this question it same as my question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631167/retain-the-dropdown-value-after-the-page-is-refresh-or-move-to-another-page-in-a/43631420#43631420

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
app.controller(.... {
    ....
    $scope.b = {};
    $scope.b.selected = localStorage.getItem("selected");
    $scope.watch("b.selected", function(item) {
        localStorage.setItem("selected", item);
    });
    ....
});
```

*EDIT*

So we suspect that the initial value gets overwritten somewhere. Here is some help how to debug it: You can define a property setter on `$scope.b`, that could alert or break to debugger. Use something like this:

```
$scope.b = {
    set selectedBudget(v) {
        debugger;
        // or alert(1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Tamas Hegedus. Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but it was unsuccessful. I was able to store data to the localStorage using your suggestion of $scope.$watch on "b.selectedBudget.year". But the issue i am having still remains. Any other suggestion is welcome.

Comment: @Christoph: And what is the issue you are having once again? I thought you had the dropdown not defaulting to the last selected value on reload.

Comment: Hi Tamas Hegedus. You are indeed correct; the dropdown still does not default to the last selected value on reload.
Any further suggestions ?

Comment: @Christoph Could you please show us the whole controller? I suspect some code overwrites the scope variable after we populate it from localStorage

Comment: I have added the whole controller as requested. I have also included the HTML file that has the drop down list. Thanks again. Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: can you answer my question ::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631167/retain-the-dropdown-value-after-the-page-is-refresh-or-move-to-another-page-in-a/43631420#43631420

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** 
This is the solution I came up with to keep the drop down list selection after webpage refresh. I hope this will help someone. I have added comments to help explain what I did. I hope they are clear. However, I welcome any correction or clarification. I was able to come up with this solution , thanks to help from @Tamas Hegedus, who pointed me in the right direction.

```js
app.controller(.... {
    ....
 (function(){
    $http.get( //Get info on budgets
        "http://localhost/TrGway/getbudgetinfo.php"
    )  
    .success(function(data){
       $scope.budgets = data.budgets; //assign array of elements to the scope variable               
        for(var i = 0; i < data.budgets.length; i++){ //Loop through each array element
            if($scope.budgets[i].year === selectedYear){ //Check if any of the 'year' value in the array match the value stored in localStorage

               $scope.b = {}; //reset the selected scope variable

               $scope.b.selectedBudget = $scope.budgets[i]; //Assign the array element with the matching year, as the selected scope element
            }      
        }                          
      
    })
    .error(function(data){
       $scope.message = "Error!! Getting Budget Info Failed: " + data;
    });
})(); 
    ....
$scope.$watch("b.selectedBudget.year", function(item) { //Set watch on array element 'year' for changes/selection
       localStorage.setItem("selectedYear", item);      //When an element is selected from the drop down list, its value is stored in localStorage 
});

});
```

```html
<select id="b_year" ng-options="b.year for b in budgets" ng-model="b.selectedBudget" ng-selected="getBudgetItems(b.selectedBudget.year)" required><option value="">-- Choose budget year --</option></select>
```